# Dimension and smoothness of a constructible set at a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a locally closed set we can define its dimension and smoothness **at a point** by taking the local stalk. Is there any official similar definition for a constructible set? Only consider over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand which sheaf's stalks are you taking to define smoothness or dimension. Suppose that $x\in X$ is a closed point of some high-dimensional variety. Then $\{x\}$ is a zero dimensional noetherian space. But by taking stalks of a structure sheaf on $X$ you pick $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and this is local ring of high Krull dimension.

Smoothness cannot be defined even for a locally closed subset. As you know in principle there are many subscheme structures on a given (locally) closed subset of a scheme. For example pick an affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ and condsider $k$-rational point $p\in \mathbb{A}^1_k(k)$. Then $p$ admits the reduced subscheme structure $\mathrm{Spec}k$ and dual numbers structure $\mathrm{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$ (and many more). The former is smooth and the latter is not.

On the other hand dimension or local dimension is purely topological notion. Hence it can be defined for any subspace whatsoever.

Comment: True. What if we only consider these over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It works for $k = \mathbb{C}$ as well.